# Accelerate/decelerate towards moving target and hitting it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a smooth camera movement in 2D. The target I want to hit can potentially move a large distance in a single frame, and is not like a character moving smoothly from A to B.

I'm aware of possible solutions like using `Vector2.Lerp()`, but that approach only slows down nicely but speeds up abruptly.

```
_position = Vector2.Lerp(_position, target, 0.5f * Time.deltaTime);
```

I've tried implementing the "arrive" steering behaviour, but cannot make it work nicely together with acceleration - especially when the target is close to the current position.

I managed to make it work pretty well in one axis, but that approach didn't work when repeated in a second axis.

```
var decelerateRadius = GetDistanceFromAcceleration(acceleration, Mathf.Abs(_velocity));
var direction = target - _position;
var distance = Mathf.Abs(direction);
var a = acceleration * Time.deltaTime;

if (distance > 0.0005f)
{
    if (distance < decelerateRadius.x)
    {
        _velocity *= distance / decelerateRadius.x;
    }
    else
    {
        _velocity += direction.x >= 0.0f ? a : -a;
    }
}
else
{
    _velocity = 0.0f;
}

// move tracker
_position += _velocity * Time.deltaTime;
```

And my method for calculating the distance based on acceleration:

```
private Vector2 GetDistanceFromAcceleration(float a, float vx, float vy)
{
    // derived from: a = (vf^2 - vi^2) / (2 * d)
    return new Vector2(vx * vx / (2.0f * a), vy * vy / (2.0f * a));
}
```

My last attempt was making a rolling average of the target, but it suffered the same issue as lerping.

To summarize the requirements:

- Must accelerate
- Must decelerate and stop at target
- Must not "orbit" or in other ways swing around the target, before stopping
- Target must be able to move
- May be limited by a maximum velocity

Any tips, pointers og solutions on how to achieve this?

---

I've also asked the question over at game dev
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/170056/accelerate-decelerate-towards-moving-target-and-hitting-it

Comment: For orbit, it is straight forward to check : if the distance between current and next position is above distance between current position and target then decelerate otherwise accelerate in direction of target. Also just like acceleration, steering can be progressive ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your lerp is also that you actually never reach the target position you just get very very close and small.

I thought about something like this

- as long as you are already at the `target`s position don't move. Enable orbit mode
- while not within a certain  `targetRadius` around the `target` position accelerate from to `maxVelocity`
- if getting within a certain `targetRadius` around the `target` position decelerate depending on the `distance / radius` will be a value between 1 and 0

To get the distance there is already [`Vector2.Distance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Distance.html) you could/should use.

For the movement I would recommend [`Vector2.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.MoveTowards.html) which also avoids overshooting of the target.

something like

```
public class SmoothFollow2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Components")]
    [Tooltip("The target this will follow")]
    [SerializeField] private Transform target;

    [Header("Settings")]
    [Tooltip("This may never be 0!")]
    [SerializeField] private float minVelocity = 0.1f;
    [SerializeField] private float maxVelocity = 5.0f;

    [Tooltip("The deceleration radius around the target.\nThis may never be 0!")]
    [SerializeField] private float targetRadius = 1.0f;

    [Tooltip("How much speed shall be added per second?\n" +
             "If this is equal to MaxVelocity you know that it will take 1 second to accelerate from 0 to MaxVelocity.\n" +
             "Should not be 0")]
    [SerializeField] private float accelerationFactor = 3.0f;


    private float _currentVelocity;
    private float _lastVelocityOutsideTargetRadius;

    private bool _enableOrbit;
    public bool EnableOrbit
    {
        get { return _enableOrbit; }
        private set
        {
            // if already the same value do nothing
            if (_enableOrbit == value) return;

            _enableOrbit = value;

            // Whatever shall be done if orbit mode is enabled or disabled
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (target == null) return;

        var distanceToTarget = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.position);

        // This is the threshold Unity uses for equality of vectors (==)
        // you might want to change it to a bigger value in order to
        // make the Camera more stable e.g.
        if (distanceToTarget <= 0.00001f)
        {
            EnableOrbit = true;

            // do nothing else 
            return;
        }

        EnableOrbit = false;

        if (distanceToTarget <= targetRadius)
        {
            // decelerate
            // This will make it slower 
            // the closer we get to the target position
            _currentVelocity = _lastVelocityOutsideTargetRadius * (distanceToTarget / targetRadius);

            // as long as it is not in the final position
            // it should always keep a minimum speed
            _currentVelocity = Mathf.Max(_currentVelocity, minVelocity);
        }
        else
        {
            // accelerate
            _currentVelocity += accelerationFactor * Time.deltaTime;

            // Limit to MaxVelocity
            _currentVelocity = Mathf.Min(_currentVelocity, maxVelocity);

            _lastVelocityOutsideTargetRadius = _currentVelocity;
        }

        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, _currentVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }


    // Just for visualizing the decelerate radius around the target
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (target) Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(target.position, targetRadius);
    }
}
```

The `MinVelocity` is actually necessary for the edge case when the target is moved not further than `TargetRadius` and `lastVelocityOutsideTargetRadius` si still `0`. In that case no acceleration takes place so `lastVelocityOutsideTargetRadius` is never updated.

With the values you have to play a bit ofcourse ;)

---

It might not be perfect yet but I hope it is a good start point to develop that further (only looks laggy due to 15 FPS for the Gif ;) )

[image]

Comment: This is great! I'll try to implement into my system. The only thing I would probably change is to calculate the `targetRadius` based on the acceleration to keep acceleration/deceleration consistent. Thanks for all the comments in your code as well :)

Comment: true you could after `_lastVelocityOutsideTargetRadius = _currentVelocity;` simply ad something like e.g. `currentRadius = TargetRadius * _currentVelocity` to let the radius grow with higher velocity